# Graph db design to GraphQL schema

Tags: javascript, graph, graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to create a graphql schema from a graph db schema I have. But I don't see how can I add properties in the graphql schema for the edges I have.

In some code:

Sample DB schema:

```
node: {
  label: 'Person',
  properties: [
   id: { type: id }
   name: { type: string }
  ]
}

edge: {
  label: 'friends'
  startNode: 'Person',
  endNode: 'Person'
  properties: {
    since: { type: date }
  }
}
```

In graphql schema should looks pretty simple:

```
var personType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'personType',
  fields: function() { return {
    id: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    name: { type: graphql.GraphQLString },
    friends: { type: graphql.GraphQLList(personType) }
  }})
});
```

But I see no way to add the property 'since' to the friends field. And i'm not finding nothing in the documentation or internet.

Is there something in the spec or I need to make new types for all edges based on the nodes adding the additional properties like 'since' and using them. 
Or something else I just can't figure out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schemas of example relay applications, [star-wars](https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/00de34d32d51ba9e4d17e45280ad6d7e2734c6ed/examples/star-wars/data/schema.js#L149-L218) project in this particular case, is very helpful. `Faction` and `Ship` play the roles of `Person` and `Friend` in your case.

You are right. In order to include the `since` property, a new type can be introduced for friend as follows (using [graphql](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-js) npm package):

```
var friendType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Friend',
  fields: {
    id: globalIdField('Friend'),
    name: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (friend) => friend.name,
    },
    since: {
      type: GraphQLString,
      resolve: (friend) => friend.since.toString(),
    },
  },
  interfaces: [nodeInterface],
});
```

In `friendType`, `since` is a string representation of the actual date. If you want a custom GraphQL type for date, you can take a look at [graphql-custom-datetype](https://github.com/soundtrackyourbrand/graphql-custom-datetype). I have not used it though.
In the `personType` that you have already defined, for `friends` field, the list element type `personType` needs to be replaced with the new `friendType`:

```
friends: { type: graphql.GraphQLList(friendType) }
```

If number of friends is large, connection or edge is recommended, as already suggested by ykad4. Once we have the definition of Friend, we can define connection for it as follows:

```
const {
  connectionType: friendConnection,
  edgeType: friendEdge,
} = connectionDefinitions({
  name: 'Friend',
  nodeType: friendType,
});
```

The field `friends` in `personType` will be updated as follows (using a helper function from [graphql-relay](https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js) npm package):

```
friends: {
  type: friendConnection,
  args: connectionArgs,
  resolve: (person) => connectionFromArray(person.friends, args),
},
```